# To INSERT INTO a database uniquely by PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database

**My table**

```
  question_id   |              title              |      user_id   |
+---------------+---------------------------------+----------------+
```

Its types are

```
                Column                 |            Type             |                            Modifiers                            
---------------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
 question_id                           | integer                     | not null default nextval('questions_question_id_seq'::regclass)
 title                                 | character varying(256)      | 
 user_id                               | integer                     |
```

I run

```
INSERT INTO questions VALUES (SERIAL, 'question title', 123);
```

I get an error about the use of SERIAL.

**How can you add the  question to the table automatically taking an unique question_id by PostgreSQL?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

DEFAULT VALUE you have will auto generate a (serial) number from a sequence that's on your DataBase. So you can just do a simple:

```
insert into questions (title, user_id) values ('question_title', 123);
```

It will insert an AUTO INCREMENTED number in **question_id** field because of ** questions_question_id_seq** sequence.

Alternatively, instead of using SERIAL, on your insert clause, you could also use the sequence. But I would rather use the first sentence I suggested:

```
insert into questions values (nextval('questions_question_id_seq'), 'question_title', 123);
```

Comment: If there is a column `was_sent_at_time` in the table, I would like know how you can add automatically the time to the new column. My unsuccessful attempt uses the method `now()` and explicit column name in the brackets: `INSERT INTO questions(title, user_id, wast_sent_at_time) VALUES ('Lorem Ipsun.', 123, now())`. **How can you add the time also to the table?**

Comment: @Masi: set the was_sent_at_time column type to the following: timestamp not null default current_timestamp

Comment: @Masi: listen to maksymko. Use the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP value to populate you was_sent_at_time column. :-)

Comment: Thank you guys! - Your last tip simplifies my SQL queries a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

*Normally*, you don't need to specify the unique id, as this is done server-side. You should use following:

```
INSERT INTO questions (title, user_id) VALUES ('question title', 123);
```

Automatic id handling is done by 'questions_question_id_seq' sequence as you may see in modifier section.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create table using

```
Create Table tbl_1 ( id SERIAL , name varchar(30));
```

You can go on inserting  data like

```
insert into tbl_1(name) values('xyz');
```

This will create the id automatically. 
Using Serial is equivalent to the sequence only.
You can check [link text](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/datatype.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)